# Add a key, value pair to a sol mapping in stylus?

Tags: arbitrum, rust, stylus

In my stylus contract, I have the following `sol_storage`:

```rust
sol_storage! {
    #[entrypoint]
    pub struct SimpleStorage {
        mapping(string => string) name_to_favorite_number;
    }
}
```

And, I have a public function I'd like to use to update the mapping:

```rust
    pub fn add_person(&mut self, name: String, favorite_number: U256) -> Result<(), Vec<u8>> {
        // add a person to the mapping of people
        // ?????
        Ok(())
    }
```

How do I add the value into the mapping?

Answer (score 1):

When you add `mapping(string => string) name_to_favorite_number;` into your contract `SimpleStorage`, you behind-the-scenes add a `StorageMap<String, StorageUint<256, 4>>` object to `self` as `name_to_favorite_number`.

So, you can access it by:

```rust
let name_to_number: StorageMap<String, StorageUint<256, 4>> = self.name_to_favorite_number;
```

*Note, you can't actually run the above line because you can't copy out this, but you have to use a function to interact with it... see more below.*

This `StorageMap` object then acts similar to a solidity `mapping`, and you can get a `StorageGuardMut<'_, V>` object which acts as a sort of mapping "setter".

Where passing the `name` as the key will allow you to set the value.

```rust
let name_to_number_setter = name_to_number.setter(name)
```

Then, you can set the value:

```rust
name_to_number_setter.set(favorite_number)
```

The whole function would look like:

```rust
    pub fn add_person(&mut self, name: String, favorite_number: U256) -> Result<(), Vec<u8>> {
        let mut name_to_favorite_number_setter = self.name_to_favorite_number.setter(name);
        name_to_favorite_number_setter.set(favorite_number);
        Ok(())
    }
```

Or, minimized:

```rust
    pub fn add_person(&mut self, name: String, favorite_number: U256) -> Result<(), Vec<u8>> {
        self.name_to_favorite_number
            .setter(name)
            .set(favorite_number);
        Ok(())
    }
```